# Difference between usePreset and useStyle in Joomla v4

Tags: joomla-4.x

I am trying to create my own theme and I see from cassiopeia theme

```
$wa->usePreset('template.cassiopeia.' . ($this->direction === 'rtl' ? 'rtl' : 'ltr'))
```

When I tried to use the same as in my template

```
$wa->usePreset('libs');
```

Its throwing error

```
$wa->useStyle('libs');
```

works fine.

Can someone explain the difference between usePreset and useStyle, and when to use?

Answer (score 3):

A `useStyle('libs')` will include or load in your page a Web Asset with a type of CSS named `libs` that has been previously registered either dynamically or as part of the components `joomla.asset.json` file.

A Preset is a collection or profile of .css and .js Web Assets(definitions) that have been registered, normally in the `joomla.asset.json` file, and the `usePreset` command will load all of the .css and .js files defined in the preset definitionin your page.

I found this a good explanation of how to use Web Assets in a component that might be helpful in you understanding what is going on, https://www.dionysopoulos.me/book/concepts-webassetmanager.html

You will find the joomla.asset.json files for each extension, including templates in the `../media/exetension_name` directories